# Receiving donations without others finding out my real name

Tags: money-transfer, gifts, donation

First a little bit of context:

- I've written a book that I've self published.
- The book is under a pen name because I care about my privacy.
- I also have a blog.
- people that read my book might visit my blog.
- I want to add a "Donate" section on my blog for people that might wish to send me some money instead of buying the book or in addition to that.

My question is, what options are there to receive donations without revealing who I really am?

With PayPal for example you need to have your real name and picture on the account so that people see who they are sending money to. I can't use my PayPal account because it has my real name on it, not my pen name. Creating another account is against their T&C, while creating a business account seems overkill.

Patreon might work too, but that's mostly for accessing exclusive content or financing a person to produce more content, so not really for donations.

Cryptocurrencies are an also an option, and I've also discovered buymeacoffee.com.

What other options are there?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this person is asking about online privacy not personal finance.